# run gbak.exe by shellexecute in c++

Tags: c++, shellexecute

I want to run `gbak.exe` file from my *MFC* application to backup *firebird DB*,
i use this order but it didn't work:

```
shellexecute(hwnd,"open","gbak.exe"," -user HAMED -password 1234 DB2.FDB b.fbk","",SW_SHOW);
```

my problem is about gbak and firebird.

can every on help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CreateProcess instead, something like this:

```
STARTUPINFO si = { 0 };  
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };  

si.cb = sizeof(si); 

std::string sCommand = "gbak.exe -user HAMED -password 1234 DB2.FDB b.fbk"

BOOL bStart = ::CreateProcess(NULL,(LPSTR) sCommand.c_str(),NULL,NULL,FALSE,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi);

if (bStart)
{
 // Wait 2 minutes or something for the process to complete
 ::WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess,1000*(2*60));
 CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
 CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
}else
{
  DWORD dwLast = GetLastError();
  printf("Error %d",dwLast);
}
```

Comment: CreateProcess is a Win32 function call, no problem to use it from an MFC application.

Comment: I used this code and program went to if(bstart) but at the end file b.fbk doesn't exit in my application folder.

Comment: Did you wait for the process to complete ? Sounds like you just singled stepped over Createprocess ?

Comment: thanks  RA, this is correct but my problem is about gbak and  firebird.

Answer (score 0):

Is the directory where `gbak.exe` is located in in your system path? If not, put it into your systems `%PATH%` variable or specifiy a fully qualified path name when calling `shellexecute` or `createprocess`.

Comment: gbak.exe is in my application folder

Answer (score 0):

change "gbk.exe" so that it is a full path. Something like:

```
c:\Program Files\thunderbird\gbak.exe"
```

Also, you misspelled `gbak.exe` as `gbk.exe`

Comment: but gbak is in my application folder.

Answer (score 0):

Program should disconnect from Data Base and then give back up.